# Aligning objects in HTML

Tags: html

I am having much difficulty making these align properly.
The code is this:

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-left:10px;">
  <div>
    <label class="inline right" for="ADD2">Address 2</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 525px;" id="ADD2"></input>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px; ">
  <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
  <input id="DOB"></input>
</div>


<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px; ">
  <label for="GEN">GENDER</label>
  <div>
    <select style="width:75px; height:25px;" id="GEN">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is for the label DOB to line up with the other labels and then the actual objects should also line up. I feel I tried all combinations but I am sure I am missing something very simple.

Right now, it looks like the image below.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: try to learn about `flexbox`. it's fun and very useful

Comment: The code provided doesn't seem to render like your screenshot; possible that the code is incomplete? Do you want the labels above the inputs, or on the same horizontal line?

Answer (score 1):

First inputs are self enclosing, so you do not put a `</input>` at the end. Second the DOB isn't inline with the rest of them because it is the only one that was not closed in its own div see below

```
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-left:10px;">
  <div>
    <label class="inline right" for="ADD2">Address 2</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 525px;" id="ADD2">
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px; ">
  <div>
    <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="DOB">
  </div>
</div>


<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px; ">
  <label for="GEN">GENDER</label>
  <div>
    <select style="width:75px; height:25px;" id="GEN">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
Edited per showdevs comment, I didn't realize they were all nested when I glanced through.
```

Comment: Agreed. But for consistency, I think the "DOB" one should have nested `<div>` elements like the other two. `<div><div><label></div><div><input></div></div>`. Alternatively, maybe get rid of the inner `<div>` elements altogether and just set `label {display:block;}` [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xk5robjg/2/).

Comment: Oh and incidentally, using the `<div>` method, only one of either the `<label>` or `<input>` needs to be wrapped in a block `<div>` (like you have in the "GENDER" one). Not really a big deal though.

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-left:10px;">
    <div style="display:inline">
        <label class="inline right" for="ADD2">Address 2</label>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; display: inline; margin-left: 10px;">
        <input type="text" style="width: 525px;" id="ADD2"></input>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px; ">
    <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
    <input id="DOB"></input>
</div>


<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px; ">
    <label for="GEN">GENDER</label>
    <div style="float: right;display: inline;">
        <select style="width:75px; height:25px;" id="GEN">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that did not make any difference.

Comment: I just illustrated how to align label and input. it is giving expected output. Please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/manpreet_cool/cxw9pg9n/2/. Moreover you can add 
<div style="float:clear; margin-top:10px;">

</div>
to separate label and input blocks  into lines.

Comment: Your code does not place the label above the object as I need. Aligning everything in a single row is not what I was asking about.